# sending device type through mail compose

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Not sure if this is possible, I have an application with a support page.  This gives the user option to mail me direct from within the application, it opens up mail.app when called.

Is it possible to preset the body of the composed email to display the device type and iOS version that the user is running?  I am using this code to predefine the body of the email;

```
NSString *emailBody = @"Can This Be Changed To Display Users Device & iOS version";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
```

The above code works fine and does populate the body field but wondered if you can display device type, i.e iPhone 4, 3GS etc

Thanks

Comment: @Joe - No idea Joe, someone voted it down.  I assumed it was because I requested the UDID information, which I guess is a no no.

Comment: No UDID is fine as long as you use it for something purposeful not just for sake of collecting the data (but apple really doesnt know what your doing with it).

Comment: Well I changed the wording of the question, the device type and iOS version would really be the useful parts to me.  But I dont know why someone voted it down, seems strange you can just vote a question down then shirk off into the darkness without reason ha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the device UDID use the code:

```
valueudid=  [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

To get the device model:

```
 value = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]
```

To get the device name:

```
 value = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]
```

More info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

Comment: thanks for the reply, where exactly what I use that in relation to what I posted for the emailBody ?

Comment: You can fetch the values in an nsstring and then add them to your emailbody.